# kivymd Error 'kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class'

Tags: kivy

soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion.  Estoy siguiendo tutoriales de kivymd, framework de python y tengo el problema de que al ejecutar los scripts. Existen clases nativas (widgets nativos, como MDTextFieldRound y MDToolbar) que el lenguaje no me reconoce. Arrojando los siguentes errores
kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class 
kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class 
Debo tener algun problema con la instalacion en la cual no se instalaron estas y seguramente otras librerias, pero no tengo idea de donde esta el error.

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda que me puedan prestar

Answer (score 1):

Es un bug conocido que fue arreglado en una versión posterior. Actualiza la versión de kivymd con este comando:

```
pip install kivymd==0.104.2
```

Comment: Gracias por la informacion.... Agradecido...

Answer (score 0):

En el changelog puedes encontrar las nuevas definiciones, ambas clases han sido cambiadas, ya en la version 1.1.0 debes usar MDTextField y MDAppBar. La documentacion oficial actualizada explica como ajustar las propiedades para obtener el efecto equivalente a sus homologos de versiones anteriores.